# Good practise or good practice?

Tags: adverbs, homophones

I believe the noun is practice and the verb is practise, as demonstrated in;

> The doctor with a private practice practises privately

However, if I wanted to say:

> It is good practi(s/c)e to colour-coordinate wires

Which is correct when you are using it as an adverb?

Comment: You are not even using "practice" as an adverb in your sample sentence. I don't think an adverb form exists.

Answer (score 4):

In British English, practise is the verb and practice the noun. In American English practice is both the verb and noun. In the phrase 'it is good practice', the word 'practice' is a noun, not an adverb, and thus *It is good **practice** to colour-coordinate wires*.

[Practice or practise?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/practice-practise/)